# Pandas Groupby - enumerate through Dataframe and copy into new, unique Excel Worksheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, for-loop, pandas-groupby

So, the data in the linked picture below is on one sheet in an Excel workbook, that was created by appending a bunch of Excel files together using Pandas (I’ve added the first column “Row#” for illustrative purposes only).

[Picture of my dataset:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZD3k.png)
What I’m trying to do is enumerate through the unique combinations of “Year” and “Scenario” and copy that data into a new workbook.  Also, in that new workbook, I want a unique worksheet made for each unique combination along with all its data.

For example, a new excel workbook would be created, the first tab in that workbook would be titled “2020 Actuals” and that worksheet would contain ONLY the first row in the picture above (where it has Year = 2020 and Scenario = Actuals). It would also include all the headers in the above screenshot as well for each new worksheet.  The next worksheet in that same workbook would be titled “2020 Plan” and would contain rows 2 – 5.  The third worksheet would be titled “2020 Fcsst” and only include rows 6 and 7 (and include the headers). And so on and so on.

So essentially I’m trying to create unique worksheets for each specific combination/concatenation of Columns Year and Scenario. I’m not trying to pivot or sum or aggregate the values in the “Jan” or “Feb” columns in any way.  Just trying to slice each unique Year-Scenario combo into a new Excel worksheet. I know this can be done with a "for loop" and a pandas groupby but can't quite get it.

This is as far as I got, but get this error --> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test2.xlsx')
grouped = combined.groupby(['Year','Scenario'])

for name, group in grouped:
    group.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
writer.save
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to groupby in order to do this, just need to filter the dataset. (If you do need to groupby to get aggregations, do that first and then start w/ the below).

You'll also need to install xlsxwriter by using `pip install xlsxwriter`

General idea is to find the unique groupings, and iterate through them filtering down the dataset and writing to each sheet.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# Create randomized dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[random.choice(['2010', '2011', '2012']) for _ in range(100)],
                   'Scenario':[random.choice(['Plan', 'Actuals', 'Fcsst']) for _ in range(100)],
                   'Val':list(range(0, 100))})

# You can sort values here if you want, but you don't have to
df = df.sort_values(['Year', 'Scenario'])
df.head()

    Year Scenario  Val
5   2010  Actuals    5
14  2010  Actuals   14
31  2010  Actuals   31
64  2010  Actuals   64
69  2010  Actuals   69

# Define your list of unique concatenations of Year and Scenario.
unique_ys = df[['Year', 'Scenario']].drop_duplicates().values.tolist()
#or
unique_ys = list(df.groupby(['Year', 'Scenario']).groups)
unique_ys

[('2010', 'Actuals'),
 ('2010', 'Fcsst'),
 ('2010', 'Plan'),
 ('2011', 'Actuals'),
 ('2011', 'Fcsst'),
 ('2011', 'Plan'),
 ('2012', 'Actuals'),
 ('2012', 'Fcsst'),
 ('2012', 'Plan')]

# Initialize a writer object, and determine the filename
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('finance_file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Iterate through unique concatenations, filter the datasets and write them to each sheet.
for list_ in unique_ys:
    df[(df.Year == list_[0]) & (df.Scenario == list_[1])].to_excel(writer, 
                                                                   sheet_name=list_[0]+' '+list_[1], 
                                                                   index=False)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH.  One slight change and it worked perfectly.  I had to add str to the list:


```
to_excel(writer, sheet_name=(str(list_[0]))+' '+list_[1], index=False)
                                                                                    
```

Comment: A co-worker also ended up showing me a way to do this with groupby after all:

'writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test4.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for yearscenario, df_chunk in combined.groupby(['Year', 'Scenario']):
    df_chunk.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= str(yearscenario[0])+ ' '+str(yearscenario[1]), index=False)
    

writer.save()
writer.close()`